# Firestore bandwidth size

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, synchronization, bandwidth, data-synchronization

For my application it is important to synchronize data between the client and server constantly. I'm thinking of integrating Firestore in my application, but I am wondering what the bandwidth of my collection(s) would be.

As I see it, every time Firestore synchronizes client side and server side, it fetches the entire collection from the server side and checks the differences between the two on the client side. This is a crude, but effective strategy. However, I can't be pulling in what is currently 100kb of database data every few seconds.

The application is loaded onto tablets that have a monthly max of 10GB 4G data. I can't exceed this limit and I don't intend to. By my calculations running this application with a sync of every 10 seconds on 1 tablet for 8 hours a day, 31 days a month, it will use **8.928GB** of data. This would suffice for now, but what do I do when my collection size grows to 200 or 300kb?

**My question:**
How often does Firestore sync data and is there any way I can avoid pulling in the entire collection every single time while still keeping 100% data integrity?

Comment: " As I see it, every time Firestore synchronizes client side and server side, it fetches the entire collection from the server side and checks the differences between the two on the client side."
That is not at all how Firestore works. The client and server work together in an effort to minimize the bandwidth used to keep the documents your application requests in sync. I'd highly recommend trying this in code before making further assumptions, and if you then still have questions posting back with the code you wrote, the behavior you observed and what you expected.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the comment. I will definitely write some code for testing purposes and post my results here so others can see them as well.